# JPA/JDBC query too slow while querying in DataGrip is fast

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I have a Transaction table with 100,000 records and an API in spring boot app to fetch and process all of the records. However, I get a query performance problem. It takes around 10 minutes to fetch all records with JPA.

```
List<Transaction> transList = transactionRepository.findAll();
```

Then, I try to use JDBC instead, but the performance is bad as well. It takes around 9 minutes to fetch all records.

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
try {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
    stmt = conn.createStatement();

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM transaction";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    conn.close();
}
```

However, when I make such a query in DataGrip, it only takes 1 minute to fetch 100,000 records.

```
select * from TRANSACTION;
```

How can I further troubleshoot what makes the JPA/JDBC query so slow?

Comment: DataGrip also uses JDBC to execute the query. Are you sure DataGrip fetches all records (and not just the first page of records).

Comment: Yes, I fetches all records (100,000)

Comment: Change the row fetch size to 100,000 by calling stmt.setFetchSize​(100000) prior to calling executeQuery.

Comment: @JeandeLavarene You are right. I find out the problem is that I haven't set fetch size for querying large data set.